# Can I have more playthroughs saved?

Tags: dishonored

I have only one playthrough so far, didn't use the manual save since I knew there were autosaves. When I want to replay a mission it warns me that if I do that my autosaves will be overwritten... So I guess I'm asking if I can avoid that somehow by using the manual save to keep my autosaves-have all my playthroughs saved (I'm kind of an OCD)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual saves are not overwritten by autosaves, so you'll be able to save different playthroughs.